# how can convert geometry type to geometry(Point)?

Tags: postgis

I think my question is stupid but I'm blocking. I just work with postgis ST_Line_Locate_Point function (linestring, point). to find the ends of lines. My problem is that my objects geometry type, not point. So how can I convert the geometry to geometry (point) ..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get identify a geometry's type use the [GeometryType](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/GeometryType.html) function.

```
SELECT GeometryType(ST_AsText('LINESTRING(1 2, 3 4, 5 6)'));
```

That returns 'LINESTRING'. You can put in any geometry and it will give back the type.

Expanding on @Nicklas' and @simplexios's answers, you can use the [ST_DumpPoints](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html) function to return the points of a line in order. Note that this is a set-returning function which means that it returns a **set** of rows formed by a geometry (given by .geom) and an **array** of integers (given by .path).

**Edit:** You can also extract the GeometryType at the same time.

```
SELECT
    (line.a).path, ST_AsText((line.a).geom), GeometryType((line.a).geom)

FROM ( SELECT
    ST_DumpPoints(ST_AsText('LINESTRING(1 2, 3 4, 5 6)')) as a
    ) as line;
```

That one returns:

```
"{1}";"POINT(1 2)";"POINT"
"{2}";"POINT(3 4)";"POINT"
"{3}";"POINT(5 6)";"POINT"
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer.The objects are  the result of ST_Intersection and their type is geometry. I tried with GeometryType and she returned  Point and Multipoint type.
I try to use ST_DumpPoints and it returns a geometry_dump.
But I can not apply ST_line_locate_point (geom, point) in this case.
 How can I access the geometry type Point by ST_DumpPoints  that returns {INT},POINT?

Comment: I added another field to the example that gives the geometry type. Does that help?

Answer (score 3):

If you want the end of line why not use
[ST_EndPoint](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_EndPoint.html)

If it is all the points you want then use [ST_DumpPoints](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_DumpPoints.html)

EDIT:

You use ST_DumpPoints like this:

```
SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom as geom from my_table;
```

to det the geometry part of the dump type.

Comment: I want exactly all the vertices of linestring in order .

Comment: st_dump return path and points

Comment: Just i don't understant the similarity of geometry dump type and geometry point?

Comment: @inesjg, see update